# Sheet music artwork

Tags: copyright, music

I would like to take sheet music collection inherited from my grandfather and use the artwork covers to create a coffee table book. I am not copying any of the music, but I will be including photos of the covers. Most of these songs are from 1910-1970s. Is the artwork copyrighted with the music?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in (US, EU, UK, Canada, somewhere else)?

Comment: What do you mean by "with the music"?  In principle, the artwork is protected by copyright _separately_ from the music.  In jurisdictions where the period of copyright is based on the life of the author, the separate nature of the copyright would be significant except in cases where the cover art was provided by one of the authors of the song, which would be highly unusual.